# Dynamics 365: Get originating field information

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have 2 lookups on the same entity at a form and I want to define the field from which Quick Create Form was opened and depending on the field, to default values on Quick Create Form. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to customize the create button behavior before launching the quick create screen from lookup control and populate few fields on load of QC form.

Native CRM lookup - ‘Create New’ hyperlink cannot be customized as of today unfortunately.

Either you can train users to manually fill the necessary field values. Or develop custom buttons (in ribbon or embedded PCF/web resource next to lookup) to launch the QC form, then populate fields on QC form load based on requirement. [Read more](https://learntoinspire.ca/2020/03/04/how-to-open-a-quick-create-phone-call-through-a-custom-ribbon-button/)